# Is nvarchar 0-indexed?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Is the max length configuration for `nvarchar` 0-indexed, e.g. If I declare column `x` as type `nvarchar` and set the max length to `(2)`: `(X nvarchar(2))` does that mean that the column takes 3 nvarchars? or only 2?

Comment: Took me a minute to parse your question. In a DBA forum *Indexed* will seldom be associated with [numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) :)

Comment: Besides what @RemusRusanu commented, "0-indexed" in the sense you are asking has to do with the numbering of the array elements, (i.e. if the first element is `array[0]` or `array[1]` or whatever) and not with the length of the array. C arrays are 0-indexed but an array of `int[5]` has 5 elements, too, much like a SQL Server `nvarachar(5)`. The numbering (or indexing) used in various functions though like `SUBSTRING()` is 1-indexed.

Comment: The column will take up to 4 bytes for the 2 dbcs characters and, usually, two bytes in the column offset array.

Comment: *zero-based* would probably be a better phrase than zero-indexed. Indexed has extra meaning in databases and zero-based is a common phrase with reference to array/list indexing in programming languages.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite clearly explained in the documentation. The value in parentheses indicates the **string length**. So `nvarchar(2)` has a string length of 2.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186939.aspx

> nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]  Variable-length Unicode string data. n
>   defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: No, Nvarchar(2) takes only 2. Parameter value is literal and not 0 indexed.